# Approximations using derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, approximation

I came across the following definitions in my textbook:

1. The differential of $x$, denoted by $dx$, is defined by $dx = \Delta x$
2. The differential of $y$, denoted by $dy$, is defined by $dy=f'(x) dx$ or 
   $dy = (\frac{dy}{dx})\Delta x$

I understood the first part. However, the second part doesn't make intuitive sense to me. What is the intuitive explanation for the second definition?

Comment: First of all, could you please be a little bit more specific as to what exactly you don't understand? Second of all, remember that's a definition. That's how it's defined.

Comment: I know that it is a definition. But I'm not able to digest the equation as there is a delta x in an equation containing derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of derivative as slope of  the tangent line to the graph of $y=f(x)$ at the point $(x,f(x))$

If you approximate your function with its tangent line, then $$m=f'(x)=\frac {dy}{dx}$$ where $dy$ is the linear approximation  to $\Delta y$ which is the actual change in $y$

As you see,$$ f'(x)=\frac {dy}{dx}$$  could be written as $$dy=f'(x) dx$$

Comment: Got that! However, what does the next equation with the delta x mean?

Comment: The first equation is simply a special case of the second equation with the function $f(x)=x$,that is for $y=x$ you get $dy = 1 dx$ because the derivative in this case is simply $1$. Since $y=x$ is linear the linear approximation $dy$ is the exact change in $y$ which is $dx=\Delta x$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think of it that way

Comment: Thank you for your attention and understanding.

Comment: I'm obliged to thank you for your detailed and thoughtful explanation!

Answer (score 2):

If $\Delta x$ is sufficiently close to $0$, then $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\approx\frac{dy}{dx}$ where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ denotes the derivative of $f(x)$ at a particular point. That's quite an obvious fact. If we multiply both sides by $\Delta x$ (we can do that because $\Delta x\ne 0$), we'll get the following:

$$\Delta y\approx\frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x.$$

The next step is purely a notational thing. Replace $\Delta y$ with $dy$, $\Delta x$ with $dx$, $\approx$ with $=$ and you will get:

$$dy=\frac{dy}{dx}dx.$$

This is called the differential of $y$. That's how it's defined.

Comment: But in the last equation of your answer, why you have dx instead of delta x. Could you explain the difference between the two equations?

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. Thanks!

Comment: As I said, it's just notation. There is really no difference.